# What is wrong with how I am trying to parse this plist?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, plist

I am trying to convert a plist into structs and here is the plist I am trying to parse:

[image]

And here is the code I am using to parse it:

```
import UIKit

struct WhatsNew: Codable {
    let sections: [WhatsNewSection]
}

struct WhatsNewSection: Codable {
    let title: String
    let releaseDate: String
    let version: String
}

class WhatsNewViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if  let path        = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "WhatsNew", ofType: "plist"),
            let xml         = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path),
            let whatsNew = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(WhatsNew.self, from: xml)
        {
            print(whatsNew)
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Don't `try?`. Catch the error and `print` it. It's obvious. Hint: Check the type of `releaseDate`.

Comment: Don't print `error.localizedDescription`, print `error`. Don't you see the type difference `Date` (plist) - `String`(struct)?

Comment: Yes @vadian thank you!